# How to change opacity of image and merge with another image in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've been looking up on how to put two picture together, turning the top one to around 50% transparent.

So far, I managed to find this:

```
from PIL import Image

def merge():
    background = Image.open("ib.jpg")
    background = background .convert('L') #only foreground color matters
    foreground = Image.open("if.jpg")

    background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
    background.show()
```

But it only outputs a blank image.

Both are same sizes.

ib.jpg:

[image: ib.jpg]

if.jpg:

[image: if.jpg]

desired output:

[image]

Any tips for a way to do this either with a RGB or RGBA file? I should be dealing with both types (some, in fact, have alpha layer).

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `blend` function from `PIL.Image`:

```
from PIL import Image
bg = Image.open("1.jpg")
fg = Image.open("2.jpg")
# set alpha to .7
Image.blend(bg, fg, .7).save("out.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Only thing I noticed is that both files need to be the same mode (can't blend greyscale with RGB). Any idea on how to ignore background colors?

Comment: Doesn't seem the prettiest way to do it, but if you convert to grayscale then convert back to RGB, it stay grayscale, but in a RGB mode.